# Python: Why Does str.split() Return a list While str.partition() Returns a tuple?

Tags: python

Comparing Python's `str.split()` with `str.partition()`, I see that they not only have different functions (`split()` tokenizes the whole string at each occurrence of the delimiter, while `partition()` just returns everything before and everything after the first delimiter occurrence), but that they also have different return types.  That is, `str.split()` returns a `list` while `str.partition()` returns a `tuple`.  This is significant since a `list` is mutable while a `tuple` is not.  Is there any deliberate reason behind this choice in the API design, or is it "just the way things are."  I am curious.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The key difference between those methods is that `split()` returns a variable number of results, and `partition()` returns a fixed number. Tuples are usually not used for APIs which return a variable number of items.

Comment: Thanks very much.  As a Python novice, I am especially grateful for the insight on tuple return type usage in APIs in general.

Answer (score 2):

@yole answer summarise the reasoning why `partition()` returns tuple. But there is a nice way to "exploit" that fact. I found below example in "Automate the boring stuff with Python".

```
   before, sep, after = 'Hello, world!'.partition(' ')
   print(before)
```